# Are there any Java/Objective-C skills that are needed in order to write applications using Xamarin

Tags: xamarin

Are there any Java/Objective-C skills that are needed in order to write fully featured applications using Xamarin or is it pure C# that compiles into Native without *any* adjustments needed (UI for example)?

Comment: From my (little) experience, you can write an app without Java or Objective-C. However, if you are a beginner with Android development, it is useful for you to be able to at least read Java, in order to take advantage of the huge pool of documentation and examples on the Internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to such question depends on your application needs.

If it's just a **standard application without a fancy UI**, you can use Xamarin.Forms in which all the UI is written in Xaml.

If you need a **more complex UI**, you may need to use Renders, which involves a native code (ios/Android) in your app, but still you can write those renders in c#, so your'e not out of C# context, but you will have to know how Android/iOS OS system works, rather than the programming language syntax.

If you have a **highly complex UI** with interactions, then Forms is not an option, and you can use the traditional Xamarin system, but you'll need to know well how does each platform operates.

Hope it helps you to decide.